# MySQL query no results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want echo my DB results from `Session` but i get no results or errors:

```
  $_SESSION['username'];

  $link = mysqli_connect("$myHost", "$myUser", "$myPass", "$myDB");

    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }


    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['username']);


   $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where username = $username";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    echo $result;
```

Anyone know why not? Session works.

Thanks

Comment: you have wrong query. Please see the mysql documentation.

Comment: That isn't valid SQL

Comment: You need basic tutorials of simple sql queries

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: Select query should be like this :  `SELECT field1, field2,...fieldN 
FROM table_name
[WHERE Clause]`

Comment: also in connection you are passing variable within quote which will behave like constant so in place of db name it will pass `$myDB` not its value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Note that `mysqli_real_escape_string` not not safe to use without setting the defualt charset it's in the manual...A better option to protect against SQL injections is using prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your query, like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT user FROM yourtablename WHERE username = $username"
```

Where "user" is what you want to SELECT if you want to select all data, you can use "*", yourtablename is table name of table you want to select.

After your edits, your code should look like

```
  $_SESSION['username'];

  $link = mysqli_connect("$myHost", "$myUser", "$myPass", "$myDB");

    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }


    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['username']);


   $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where username = $username";
    if ($result = $link->query($sql)) {

        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            var_dump($row);
        }

        $result->close();
    }
```

More info [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

**Notice:** `mysqli_real_escape_string` it's not very security. A better option to protect against SQL injections is using prepared statements, more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Comment: Updated my Question, but the same problem. Can you check it please?

Comment: Now i get this error:  `Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in `

Comment: My bad use `$sql` instead of `$query` cuz your variable which contains sql query is with name `$sql` also, why you have `$_SESSION['username'];` in the begining ? i think it should be `session_start()`

Comment: With `var_dump()` you can see the result - yes. Can you write `var_dump($username)` before `$sql = ....` row ?

Comment: Note that `mysqli_real_escape_string` not not safe to use without setting the defualt charset it's in the manual...A better option to protect against SQL injections is using prepared statements.

Comment: @sarahlo where was your bad at the end ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, i will add this to my answer